# how to write insert query in node js using fronted html database have postgresql

Tags: html, node.js, postgresql

I am fresher just start work node js , postgrsql. Currently I am working on login form code. But I have faced many problems POST method. Use html, node js , postgresql. Please help me.... I have share code file

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
var pg = require("pg");

var conString = "pg://postgres:insta@localhost/postgres";//"pg://postgres:insta@localhost:8090/postgres";

var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();

    var formidable = require("formidable");
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    app.post('/login', function(req, res){
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields) {
    var firstname = fields.firstname;
    var lastname = fields.lastname;
    console.log(firstname);        

    if (firstname && lastname){
        client.query("INSERT INTO emps(firstname, lastname) values($1, $2)", [firstname, lastname]);
    res.send('Login Successfully');
    }else{
      res.send('Wrong firstname/lastname');
    }
    });   
    }); 

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/front-end'));     
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 8090)) // set port

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'))
})
```

**login.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang=""> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>J & B</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,200,300,500,600,800,700,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>

     $(document).ready(function () {

    $(".input_submit1").click(function () { 
    alert('Hi..');
     alert('login successfully1');
     var firstname = $('.firstname').val();
     var lastname = $('.lastname').val();
        if(firstname == '' && lastname == '')
      {
      alert('Please enter text fields...');
      }
      else
      {
      alert('login successfully');
      // EXAMPLE FOR JQUERY AJAX COMPLETE FUNC.
      $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:8090/login",
      type: "POST",
      data: {"firstname" : firstname, "lastname" : lastname},
      //dataType: 'jsonp', // Notice! JSONP <-- P (lowercase)
      headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      },
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(err){
      $('.input_submit1').val('Submit');
      }
      });
      }
      });
      })
    </script>
    </head>

    <body class="homepage">

<!--top bar-->
    <section id="top-bar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=""><img src="images/top-img1.png" alt=""><span>+1 800 603 6035</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><img src="images/top-img2.png" alt=""><span></span>mail@demolink.org</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-sm-6 col-xs-4">
                <ul class="login">
                    <li><a href="register.html"><img src="images/top-img3.png" alt=""><span>Register</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="login.html"><img src="images/top-img4.png" alt=""><span></span>Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
<!--top bar-->   

<!--navbar--> 
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="help.html">How we help</a></li>
        <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <!--<li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>-->
       <!-- <li><a href="#">Donate Now</a></li>-->
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>   
<!--navbar-->

<!-- INNER PAGE -->
<section id="inner-page-banner-contact" class="about-banner">
    <div class="container ">
        <h1>Login</h1>  
    </div>
</section>

<div class="row"></div>
<!-- END INNER PAGE -->

<section id="contact-us">
<div class="top1">
    <div class="container">

    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <form method="POST">
              <div class="col-xs-12">
              <input type="text" class="form-control firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="firstname :">
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-12">
              <input type="text" class="form-control lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="lastname :">
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button type="button" name="input_submit1" class="btn btn-default input_submit1">Login</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: If you don't explain your problems clearly nobody can help you. Please take the time to clearly explain what you're trying to do, what you've done and what is the exact problem

Comment: hi sir..i have sent to my login.html and sever.js page.
i have writen login page code.firstname and lastname there are two filed.and one submit button,
I want any user insert data in my form after submit click this data see in database BUT currently this data not see in dataabse.its actual problem.

Comment: maybe your sql-command is never committed. Try to add a colon at the end like this:  "...values($1, $2);"

Answer (score 0):

**Update the code in the server Insert query to this code**

```
if (firstname && lastname){
    client.query("INSERT INTO emps("firstname", "lastname") values($1, $2)", 
    [firstname, lastname]);
res.send('Login Successfully');
}
```

***the solution after the table name use "column Name"***

thank you ..